# Meaning of "lay preparing"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of **lie preparing** in following sentence?

> For him, the globe lay preparing quintillions of years without one
>   animal or plant.

and what he means by "without one animal or plant"? Is it idiomatic or archaic?

Comment: The globe is being compared to a person lying down, doing something.

Comment: The text is from Walt Whitman, *Leaves of Grass*. I think it should read ***For it**, the globe lay preparing...* (where ***it*** refers to a slave being auctioned, which is presumably "a dehumanization too far" for modern editors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question "without one animal or plant" means that there was not a single animal or plant in existence on Earth during that enormous span of time.

It is perfectly normal modern English. It is similar to "He goes through life without a thought for other people".